# Correct way to pass functions to handlers in 'dumb' components in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

Looking at this simple example where the prop `toggleData` would be a redux thunk action mapped to the container props.

Is this the recommended way to pass a function like this to a child 'dumb' component? I read an article online saying that using arrow functions inside handlers is expensive and not very efficient from a performance perspective.

```
class Container extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <Home toggleData={this.props.toggleData}/>
        )
    }
}

const Home = (props) => {
    return (
        <button onClick={()=>{props.toggleData()}}></button>
    )
}
```

Comment: since you don't want to pass any extra parameter from child component, so directly you can use `onClick={props.toggleData}` without creating a new function using arrow, check the last para of the [**DOC page**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes! Avoid using arrow functions inside the JSX. Because the function will be created on every render, this *might* lead to performance issues later on.

If you don't need to send parameters you can do something like this:

```
const Home = (props) => {
    return (
      <button onClick={props.toggleData}></button>
    )
}
```

If you need to use parameters, I usually define a class to create the callback using an arrow function, this way it gets created and bound only once.

```
class Home extends PureComponent {
  onToggle = () => {
    this.props.toggleData(1, 2, 3);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.onToggle}></button>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You also should use this.onToggle = this.onToggle.bind(this) in the constructor

Comment: above comment is not true - you don't need to bind the function if you use the `onToggle = () =>` (ie. as a class property) as it's executed within that class context.

Comment: Thank you ! How can you do it if we want to pass variable arguments from view (like an index) ? Are we force to do something like this : 
<button onClick={()=>{props.toggleData(index)}}></button> ?